# GlyphVector.getoutline() never returning

Tags: ikvm, apache-xml-graphics

I am trying to create a PostScript file using the Apache xml-graphics library. When I run under Java, it works fine.

But when I build for .NET using IKVM, then on a call to GlyphVector.getoutline(x, y), the code never returns.

This is happening when I:

```
AttributedString as = new AttributedString(buf.toString());
// call as.addAttribute() setting various TextAttribute for various ranges
FontRenderContext frc = graphics.getFontRenderContext();
LineBreakMeasurer lineMeasurer = new LineBreakMeasurer(as.getIterator(), frc);
TextLayout layout = lineMeasurer.nextLayout(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
layout.draw (graphics, left, line.getBaseline());
```

Any idea what can be going wrong?

thanks - dave